# How to search for a variable name in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, search, tablename

I want to search for a particular variable name in ‘PostgreSQL’ database. Similar to the following ‘Teradata’ query

```
Select TableName, ColumnName from
DBC.Columns
Where ColumnName like (‘%profile%’)
```

Is there a similar query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Postgres documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/infoschema-columns.html)

```
SELECT table_name,column_name
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE column_name  like '%profile%'
```